# Laravel 5.0 URL change for pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I want to change pagination URL for Laravel 5.0 from:

http://example.com/en/xyz?page=1

to

http://example.com/en/xyz/1

I have tried MULTIPLE solutions but nothing works for Laravel 5.0 here:

[Laravel Pagination with pretty urls than query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124593/laravel-pagination-with-pretty-urls-than-query-string?rq=1)

https://github.com/mayoz/pagination

Is there any fix available?

Comment: You have to rewrite the native pagination to use route parameter instead of GET parameters. An easy hack might be - use model ->skip() and ->take() methods. Like for example if you need 5 records per page on 3rd page you can Model::skip(3*5)->take(5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

required page variable on your route definition and set a default value

```
Route::get('en/xyz/{page?}', function($page=1) {
    $limit = 10;
    $results = SomeModel::orderBy('someField')
        ->skip($limit * $page - 1)
        ->take($limit)
        ->get();
    return $results;
});
```